# In Microsoft Azure Information Protection is there a one time passcode option?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to figure out how to allow documents encrypted with our Azure Information Protection to be read outside of the domain without an account in our Azure Active Directory. Something like a one time passcode would be perfect but anything would work as long as it allowed users outside of the AD to decrypt and access the files.

I've seen the add guest user option that would allow me to add the users e-mail to the AD but not sure if this would give me the desired effect in that it would allow the guest to see the docs.

I've been googling and all signs point to this functionality not being a part of the program but I figured I could check here as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is good article about external sharing - https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/azure-information-protection-guidance-external-sharing-joe-stocker

Basically when you share with external - if user is not Office 365 user (or does not have Azure AD account) then he is guided to create Microsoft account which is used for authentication.

You should try it out with your own external email account to feel the experience of "external user".

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

There is support in Azure information protection with gmail that does not require you to have a Microsoft Account and there is a one time password option as well
https://microsoft-my.sharepoint.com/:p:/p/kartikka/EYuUOztbsKFNtRTKGoNv3cABLyIsG8VJEiD3vpu7wyDmfA?e=EdpsVT